# How to get notification background color and dynamically change the text color based on results from background color

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I had a chance to look over some of the posts regarding background color for notification for Android but unfortunately none of the posts provide a clear answer of how I can get the notification background and based on that result dynamically change the text color. So for example is the notification background is white, it would check the color and if it sees white it will change the text color to black.
I would really appreciate if you can help me on this issue.

Comment: Would also like to know,